# Change functionality of next button in asp.net wizard

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wizard

I have a ASP wizard consisting of four steps ,

1. Add Customer id
2. Add ITEM iD.
3. Add  location.
4. Finalize

I dont want the user to go next without Entering ids and skip any step .
I have tried all events and searched a lot but next and previous buttons work as it is .

I also want to finish the option of clickable Side bar hyperlinks.

```
    if (e.CurrentStepIndex == 1)
    {
        if (LabelCustomerNotify.Text == "notset")
        {
            LabelCustomerNotify.Text = "You can not proceed without selecting customer id";
            Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = 1;
        }
        else
        {

            Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex++;
        }
    }
    else if (e.CurrentStepIndex == 2)
    {
        if (LabelItemNotify.Text == "notset")
        {
            LabelItemNotify.Text = "You can not proceed without selecting Item id";
            Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = 1;
        }
        else
        {

            Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex++;
        }
    }
    else if (e.CurrentStepIndex == 3)
    {

        Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex++;
    }
```

I have entered this code in events like Wizard1_ActiveStepChanged,Wizard1_NextButtonClick etc

Kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [WizardNavigationEventArgs.Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizardnavigationeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to cancel the move to the next step (in the `NextButtonClick` event)), rather than your current approach:

```
if (e.CurrentStepIndex == 1)
{
    if (LabelCustomerNotify.Text == "notset")
    {
        LabelCustomerNotify.Text = "You can not proceed without selecting customer id";
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

If it's still not working right, I would run a debugger and make sure that your code is actually entering that if-block.  You might just be having an issue with the condition.